# Autocomplete stay as "FIXED" while scrolling (All browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, autocomplete

I have a page with a form that built with react and on the inputs, while the user start to write something, the autocomplete open but if the user scrolling up/down the autocomplete stay at the position that it open (Like a fixed position).

**
I can't inspect this of course...

This happens on all browsers (CH, FF, IE)

Any idea...?

Answer (score 0):

All these auto complete are browser specific. It depends on browsers how they have styled and positioned their autocomplete. For some browser it is also possible to not have auto-complete feature. You can not changed it from your project you can disable them from your browsers if you want.

Comment: Ammm.... I know that I can turn on/off the autocomplete but I need this function :-(

If this is a browser issue, the writer of the browsers (Mozila, Google & Microsoft) doesn't aware for that issue and can't handle this?

Comment: But autocomplete is anyway present in your browser by default you don't need to add them.

Comment: You can also add customized auto-complete javascript plugin if you want. like this http://code.runnable.com/UdQOiCHniSpKAAV1/add-autocomplete-to-input-box-form-using-jquery

Comment: I'm not adding it.... this is the browser autocomplete.... its just STUCK in his place while it showing

Comment: So what do you want to do with it do you want to remove it or change it's position or what??

Comment: I want that the browser autocomplete will scroll apon the user scroll the page :-)

Comment: You need to use customize jquery's autocomplete so you can manipulate it. You can't manipulate autocomplete of every browser.